# SWT Browser - Detect Ajax Calls

Tags: java, ajax, browser, swt

I'm using SWT.Browser (java) and am wondering if there's a way to get a listener that hears when ajax requests are made, received, etc.

Is there a way to intercept them and manipulate them before they come in, etc?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no publicly available API for that.

However, you can write [APP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) plugin for SWT, though it is applicable to IE only. Or for Firefox or Webkit or IE you can write a local proxy like [fiddler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250446.aspx).

Comment: hmm, i'm using this on mac and windows. too bad